# Google Maps API Errors

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Why I'm receiving 3 errors
js?
 1. You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
 2. Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys
 3. Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired

I've updated my post, with the code I used

[image]

```js
          jQuery(function($) {
            // Asynchronously Load the map API
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCtUEDsZQxJvGCRtBNCHGSCmS51kJkuruo&libraries=places&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
            document.body.appendChild(script);
          });
          var icon2 = "https://d2rw3as29v290b.cloudfront.net/instances/130/uploads/ckeditor/picture/data/3224/icon2.png";
          var icon1 = "https://d2rw3as29v290b.cloudfront.net/instances/130/uploads/ckeditor/picture/data/3223/icon1.png";
          function attachClickHandler(marker){
           var elem = $(marker.url);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            console.log(marker.title);
            $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: elem.offset().top
            -250 }, 2000 );
            }),
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
            marker.setIcon(icon2);
            }),
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
              marker.setIcon(icon1);
            })

            $(marker.url).on("mouseover", function () {
                marker.setIcon(icon2);
            });
            $(marker.url).on("mouseout", function () {
               marker.setIcon(icon1);
            });
          }


          //div hover change icon
           $(document).ready(function()  {
             // initiate Google maps
              initialize();
          });

            function initialize() {
              var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
              [
                {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#705135'}]},
                {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#f5f1e6'}]},
                {
                  featureType: 'administrative',
                  elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
                  stylers: [{color: '#c9b2a6'}]
                },
                {
                  featureType: 'water',
                  elementType: 'geometry.fill',
                  stylers: [{color: '#457cbc'}]
                },
                {
                  featureType: 'water',
                  elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                  stylers: [{color: '#fff'}]
                },
                {
                featureType: "poi",
                elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
                stylers: [
                  {"color": "#cd5cb9"},
                  {
                    "visibility": "off"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                featureType: "poi.park",
                elementType: "labels.text.fill",
                stylers: [
                  {
                    "color": "#458035"
                  }
                ]
              },
                {
              featureType: "transit.line",
              elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
              stylers: [
                {
                  "color": "#cd5cb9"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              featureType: "water",
              elementType: "geometry",
              stylers: [
                {
                  "color": "#457cbc"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              featureType: "water",
              elementType: "geometry.stroke",
              stylers: [
                {
                  "visibility": "simplified"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              featureType: "water",
              elementType: "labels.text.fill",
              stylers: [
                {
                  "color": "#ffffff"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              featureType: "water",
              elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
              stylers: [
                {
                  "visibility": "off"
                }
              ]
            }
              ],
              {name: 'Styled Map'});
              var map;
              var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
              var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.8688, 151.2093);
              var mapOptions = {
                  mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
                  center: latlng,
                  zoomControl: true,
                  zoomControlOptions: {
                  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
                },
                  scaleControl: true,
                  gestureHandling: 'greedy',
                  streetViewControl: true,
                  streetViewControlOptions: {
                  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
                }
              };

              var latitude,
                  longitude,
                  dataName,
                  coor,
                  coor,
                  markers;
              var markers = [];
              google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {

              });

              $(".location").each(function() {
                latitude = $(this).attr('data-latitude');
                longitude = $(this).attr('data-longitude');
                dataName = $(this).attr('data-name');
                dataId = $(this).attr('id');
              // Multiple Markers
              markers.push([dataName, latitude, longitude, "#" + dataId])

              });
              console.log(markers);

              // Display a map on the page
              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_content"), mapOptions);
              map.setTilt(45);

              // Info Window Content
              var infoWindowContent = [
                  // ['<div class="info_content">' +
                  // '<h3>London Eye</h3>' +
                  // '<p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p>' +        '</div>'],
                  // ['<div class="info_content">' +
                  // '<h3>Palace of Westminster</h3>' +
                  // '<p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p>' +
                  // '</div>']
              ];

              // Display multiple markers on a map
              var icon1 = "https://d2rw3as29v290b.cloudfront.net/instances/130/uploads/ckeditor/picture/data/3223/icon1.png";

              var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
              // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map
              for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
                  var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
                  bounds.extend(position);
                  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: position,
                      map: map,
                      icon: icon1,
                      title: markers[i][0],
                      url: markers[i][3]
                  });
                  attachClickHandler(marker);


                  // Allow each marker to have an info window
                  // google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                  //     return function() {
                  //         infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                  //         infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                  //     }
                  // })(marker, i));
                  // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
                  map.fitBounds(bounds);
              }
              // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
              var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
                  this.setZoom(map.getZoom());
                    if (this.getZoom() > 15) {
                    this.setZoom(15);
                  }
                  google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
              });


              // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
              // fields in the form.
              //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
            map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);
            map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');
          }


            $(window).on('resize', function(event){
              var windowSize = $(window).width(); // Could've done $(this).width()
                if(windowSize < 992){
                    moveSearchNew();
                } else if(windowSize > 991){
                  moveSearchOld();
                }
            });
            marker = "https://d2rw3as29v290b.cloudfront.net/instances/130/uploads/ckeditor/picture/data/3223/icon1.png";
```

```html
<div id="map_cont">
  <div id="map_content" class="mapping"></div>
</div>

<ul class="locations">
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="23779"
            data-name=""
            data-latitude="-33.8688197"
            data-longitude="151.2092955">
            <a href="/space//listings/23779"></a>
            </li>
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="31571"
            data-name="Sydney CBD Townhall - Luggage/Stock/Archive Files/Light Equipment Storage at a Studio "
            data-latitude="-33.8718491"
            data-longitude="151.2061548">
            <a href="/space//listings/photography-studio-for-hire-inc-photography-equipments">Sydney CBD Townhall - Luggage/Stock/Archive Files/Light Equipment Storage at a Studio </a>
            </li>
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="37317"
            data-name="asd"
            data-latitude="-33.8688197"
            data-longitude="151.2092955">
            <a href="/space//listings/asd">asd</a>
            </li>
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="12615"
            data-name="Lockup Storage Garage in Drummoyne cnr Victoria Rd &amp; Lyons Rd"
            data-latitude="-33.85142"
            data-longitude="151.1537932">
            <a href="/space//listings/lockup-storage-garage-in-drummoyne-cnr-victoria-rd-lyons-rd">Lockup Storage Garage in Drummoyne cnr Victoria Rd &amp; Lyons Rd</a>
            </li>
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="21916"
            data-name="Garage Title"
            data-latitude="-33.8688197"
            data-longitude="151.2092955">
            <a href="/space//listings/garage-title">Garage Title</a>
            </li>
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="23913"
            data-name="Sydney - Lockup Garage Parking or Storage"
            data-latitude="-33.8719133"
            data-longitude="151.204284">
            <a href="/space//listings/sydney-lockup-garage-parking-or-storage">Sydney - Lockup Garage Parking or Storage</a>
            </li>
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="30172"
            data-name="World Tower Parking Space"
            data-latitude="-33.876613"
            data-longitude="151.206883">
            <a href="/space//listings/world-tower-parking-space">World Tower Parking Space</a>
            </li>
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="30733"
            data-name="Sydney CBD - Secure Undercover Parking Space"
            data-latitude="-33.877274"
            data-longitude="151.2066911">
            <a href="/space//listings/sydney-cbd-secure-undercover-parking-space-30730">Sydney CBD - Secure Undercover Parking Space</a>
            </li>
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="30882"
            data-name="Sydney CBD Secure Car Park"
            data-latitude="-33.8755146"
            data-longitude="151.2051445">
            <a href="/space//listings/sydney-cbd-secure-car-park">Sydney CBD Secure Car Park</a>
            </li>
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="30835"
            data-name="Sydney CBD Secure Parking Space (Sedan type of vehicle would fit in)"
            data-latitude="-33.8779309"
            data-longitude="151.2108431">
            <a href="/space//listings/sydney-cbd-secure-parking-space">Sydney CBD Secure Parking Space (Sedan type of vehicle would fit in)</a>
            </li>
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="35195"
            data-name="Large Storage Cage in centre of city near Town Hall"
            data-latitude="-33.877274"
            data-longitude="151.2066911">
            <a href="/space//listings/large-storage-cage-in-centre-of-city-near-town-hall">Large Storage Cage in centre of city near Town Hall</a>
            </li>
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="36060"
            data-name="Sydney - Secure Undercover Car Spot in CBD"
            data-latitude="-33.8689295"
            data-longitude="151.2043204">
            <a href="/space//listings/sydney-secure-undercover-car-spot-in-cbd">Sydney - Secure Undercover Car Spot in CBD</a>
            </li>
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="37313"
            data-name="Garage in Sydney with 24/7 Access"
            data-latitude="-33.9399228"
            data-longitude="151.1752764">
            <a href="/space//listings/garage-in-sydney-with-24-7-access-37313">Garage in Sydney with 24/7 Access</a>
            </li>
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="37306"
            data-name="Garage in Sydney with Partial Access"
            data-latitude="-33.8687953"
            data-longitude="151.2099375">
            <a href="/space//listings/garage-in-sydney-with-partial-access-37306">Garage in Sydney with Partial Access</a>
            </li>
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="37328"
            data-name="Garage in Sydney with Partial Access"
            data-latitude="-33.8686041"
            data-longitude="151.2087514">
            <a href="/space//listings/test-case-001-37324">Garage in Sydney with Partial Access</a>
            </li>
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="19322"
            data-name="Parking Available On Harris St Pyrmont NSW"
            data-latitude="-33.8727121"
            data-longitude="151.195554">
            <a href="/space//listings/parking-available-on-harris-st-pyrmont-nsw">Parking Available On Harris St Pyrmont NSW</a>
            </li>
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="30342"
            data-name="Sydney CBD Secure Undercover Car Space (shared with the owner)"
            data-latitude="-33.8734741"
            data-longitude="151.2044913">
            <a href="/space//listings/sydney-cbd-secure-undercover-car-space">Sydney CBD Secure Undercover Car Space (shared with the owner)</a>
            </li>
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="29648"
            data-name="Sydney CBD Secure Undercover Parking Space (Sedan type of vehicle would fit in) "
            data-latitude="-33.8779309"
            data-longitude="151.2108431">
            <a href="/space//listings/sydney-cbd-secure-undercover-parking-space">Sydney CBD Secure Undercover Parking Space (Sedan type of vehicle would fit in) </a>
            </li>
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="31882"
            data-name="Sydney CBD Secure Car Space In The City"
            data-latitude="-33.8755266"
            data-longitude="151.2047196">
            <a href="/space//listings/sydney-cbd-secure-car-space-in-the-city">Sydney CBD Secure Car Space In The City</a>
            </li>
            
            <li
            class="location"
            id="36197"
            data-name="4 square meters storage CBD Sydney"
            data-latitude="-33.8744294"
            data-longitude="151.204579">
            <a href="/space//listings/4-square-meters-storage-cbd-sydney">4 square meters storage CBD Sydney</a>
            </li>
            
            </ul>
```

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know any thing about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), it is basically you can't use different domain in iframe as defualt but it is possible if you get requirements. I have tested your code and it works on my local, but I need to change some codes on page.

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks, just curious what change did you make to make it working on your end?

Comment: I didn't use in any iframe or different domain, it works same domain. I didn't use your script loading _// Asynchronously Load the map API_ because it gives error continuous hence I add script tag manually below <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**yourKey**&amp;v=3.exp&amp;libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an iframe with javascript, it's a security problem thats why browsers block scripts trying to access a frame with a different origin.

[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) is more about the topic same-origin policy, you can read it.

so basicly protocol, hostname and port must be the same of your domain, if you want to access a frame.